# Logitech Anywhere Mouse - even new batteries show 'need to replace' red blinking light

Tags: mouse, battery

I have a Logitech Anywhere mouse that I've had for a while now. It's been doing great but since it last gave the orange/red blinking light showing that the battery needs to be replaced, no battery is working effortlessly anymore.

What does that mean? Basically that I buy new batteries from the store, stick them in, and the orange/red blinking persists. I move the mouse about, flip the switch on and off, press on the battery cover a few times, leave it for a while, and come back to it again... and sometimes if I'm lucky, the mouse will give a green light again and all is well. If not, I have to repeat the whole process and rely on my touchpad until the mouse decides to work again.

I know the best thing may be to just buy a new mouse now, but I want to know if there's some way to fix this since I've loved this mouse so much and maybe there's some simple solution to it. I'm guessing maybe there's some issue in the connection of the on/off switch at the bottom?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the metal contacts in the battery compartment?

Comment: They look clean but I did clean them several times actually. Is there some special way to clean them? The metal contact nodes on a car battery are usually cleaned with hot water for instance...

Comment: People often recommend using isopropyl alcohol and a cotton swab for that sort of thing. But if the contacts are already quite clean then it may not help in which case there may be a badly soldered joint inside the mouse or something. If you have a friend who is handy with a soldering iron and a multimeter then they might be able to repair it.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this same issue. The 3 x orange 1 x red flashes is an error code rather than low battery.

I've managed to get my mouse to work while holding the right mouse button down for at least one second while switching it on.

Comment: This worked for me like magic. But it keeps blinking orange on startup. Couldn't find any information on this error... any help/directions/urls?

Answer (score 2):

I've just held down on the right mouse button (and a few others) while powering it on and nothing worked.

I've tried various combinations but it was when I decided to keep holding  right mouse buttons and both small thumb buttons on the side and held for a longer time when I got a brief yellow light after about 15 sec. After that, I was able to power on with a green light and all is well.

There seem to be different RESET scenarios with different button combinations. Just try all of them and remember to keep holding down for longer than 10-15sec. That's the part I've never read anywhere else so far. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED (for me, anyway)]

Nothing else worked for me, but Tom Blair's answer inspired me to more closely check out the connections. I already cleaned and brushed the contacts, but I noticed that one of the batteries fit very loosely--not snugly in the battery compartment. So I carefully bent the NEGATIVE contact (because the POSITIVE contact is not movable) out slightly, and now the battery fits snugly and when it powers on: all green!

Answer (score 0):

I pushed down on the scroll button while switching it on and this appeared to work as the green light came on. This was several days ago and it’s still working, with the existing batteries! In fairness, I held the scroll button down for about 10-15 seconds before switching the button on.

Answer (score 0):

None if these have worked for me.. what am I doing wrong? I've done all three combinations and none of them worked. My mouse is still flashing the orange and red lights. What do I do?

So update..  I got the green light. Turns out after i held down all four main buttons; left mouse, right mouse, middle button and the scroll button, I managed to get the green light. I held all four buttons down for a solid 10 sec I think. Maybe more. But now it no longer blinks

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned and brushed the contacts, it wasn't enough, I had to unscrew the mouse and clean the soldering of the power cable because before i had leaking battery.

find instruction Logitech Anywhere Mouse MX Full Disassembly
https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Logitech+Anywhere+Mouse+MX+Full+Disassembly/90192

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1122644)

Answer (score -1):

Some replaceable batteries do not have a long enough positive end to make contact with the battery holder. If this is the case, then the red flashing light will be the result. Try putting a small piece of wire on the positive tip of the battery. This will help the battery make contact with the holder and it will then work fine.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. No contact with the battery means no power to make a red flashing light...